# Help with a simple queueing model question to find transition probabilities?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

My prof posted a set of practice questions for our upcoming midterm and I'm trying to work through them (he's not posting solutions for them).  He included this question as the most difficult one.

A device services customers one at a time such that if it is handling a customer at time $n$, it has probability $p$ of finishing their service before time $n+1$.

In that case it begins servicing the next waiting customer at time $n+1$.

Between time $n$ and time $n+1$, $Z_n$ customers arrive, where $Z_n$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $/lambda$ and is independent of past arrivals.

Let $X_N$ be the number of customers both awaiting service and being served at time $n$.  So the total number of customers at time $n$.

First we are supposed to show that ${X_n, n≥0}$ is a Markov chain, and then we are supposed to find the transition probabilities for all $i, j$.

I'm really not sure where to get started with this one - he posted it as a "difficult" midterm question to practice with, and it seems really unfamiliar.  We haven't actually done queueing theory in class so there must be another way to do it but I'm really not sure.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_n=$ the number of customers served between time $n$ and $n+1.$ $P(I_n=1)=p, P(I_n=0)=1-p.$

If $X_n>0,X_{n+1}=Z_n+X_n-I_n   $

If $X_n=0,X_{n+1}=Z_n$

This shows $X_{n+1}$ depends on the past only through $X_n$ and through $Z_n$ which is independent of the past. So $\{{X_n}\}$ is a Markov chain.

Let $P_{ij}$ be the one-step transition probability (which does not depend on $n$). Let $g(k)={\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}/k!$

Then $P_{0,j}=g(j).$

For $i>0,P_{i,i-1}=g(0)p.$

For $i>0,j\ge 0,P_{i,i+j}=g(j)(1-p)+g(j+1)p.$